# Need help understand polynomial factorisation technique.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

First off I tried formatting this as best as I could (still new to LaTeX).
My lecturer showed an example of a technique to factor polynomials with a degree $\ge$ 4 but I am having trouble understanding it.

We have that $ \deg p \geq 4,  \deg p = r + s $ in the following

$$ p(x) = (a_r x ^r)+...+a_0)(b_sx^s+...+b_0) $$

We want to examine:

$$\begin{aligned} p(x) &= x^4 + 1 \\
&= (x^2 + ax + b) (x^2 + cx + d) \\
&=x^4+(a+c) x^3 + (ac+d+b)x^2 + (ad+bc)x + bd 
\end{aligned}$$

Coeffiant comparison:

```
I:        a + c = 0
II:  ac + b + d = o
III:    ad + bc = 0
IV:          bd = 1
```

$ I\Rightarrow \;a=-c \; ^{III}_{\Rightarrow}\; b=d \;(if \; c\ne0)\; ^{IV}_{\Rightarrow}\; d^2=1 \Rightarrow d=\pm 1$  Choose d=1

$II \Rightarrow c^2 = 2 \Rightarrow c= \pm\sqrt{2}$

Choose c= $\sqrt{2} \Rightarrow a=-\sqrt{2} $

$ \Rightarrow  x^4+1 = (x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)$

Comment: what part of it exactly are you not understanding?

Comment: Plugging p(x) into the technique. to get x^4+1 = (x^2 + ax + b) (x^2 + cx + d)

Comment: here, we are decomposing $p(x)$ into a product of two quadratics. then, upon expansion, we use coefficient comparisons to determine what $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are.